# Selenium SeleniumTestCase .checkForVerificationErrors method : output status before it fails

Tags: selenium, junit4

I am testing a table on a webpage where i need to verify all values in table.
For this i have written a `for` loop 
something like this

```
for (row) {
   for (column) {
       SeleniumTestCase.verifyTrue( "expected".equals("obtained"));
   }
   SeleniumTestCase.checkForVerificationErrors();
}
```

Here in the fifth line i am checking was their any error in any of the columns at this row.

Problem is if their is any error, i can not output at which row and columns error was detected as [checkForVerificationErrors](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestCase.html#checkForVerificationErrors()) method will fail immediately without letting me to output any debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JUnit TestCase assertions instead:

```
for (row) {
   for (column) {
       SeleniumTestCase.assertEquals("Verifying row " + row + ", column " + column, 
               expected, obtained);
   }
}
```